# Can I change the linear velocity limitation in turtlebot3?

Tags: ros-melodic

I’m using turtlebot3 for my experiment. (also, ros1 and melodic)

For my experiment, the linear velocity limitation of turtlebot3 needs to be changed. As I know, the linear velocity limation is 0.22 m/s. But I want to changed the limitation, till 0.25 m/s.

To change the linear velocity limitation, I tried some ways.

1. Modify

   ```
   turtlebot3_teleop_key
   ```

   file with sudo authority in

   ```
   opt/ros/melodic/lib/turtlebot3_teleop
   ```

   folder.
2. Use other ros teleop packages

But it didn’t work.

Is there any possible way to change the linear velocity limitation?

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: It is a bad idea to modify files within /opt/ros/ tree until you know much more about ros - you can easily break other parts of ros. Please edit your question to show us the exact commands you are using to launch `turtlebot3_teleop_key`. Format the commands as code.